# presentPopoverFromRect causes my app to freeze

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller

I am showing a Popover from a Button which is placed in the header of a UITableView.

```
-(void) addButtonClicked:(id)sender{

 [addPopOverVC setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(POPOVER_WIDTH, numberOfRowsInTable * addOptionsTable.rowHeight)];
 [addPopOverVC presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds] inView:sender 
                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; 
 addPopOverVC.passthroughViews = nil;
}
```

the app freezes on the second line (when I call method presentPopoverFromRect) without any warning / error in debugger. Also when I try to debug it the step over just disappears at that line and app becomes unresponsive as if it never returned back. 
I havent seen such a behavior before . addPopOverVc is a UIPopoverViewController. all parameters have  values which are not nil .

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean to use the frame rectangle and not the bounds rectangle.

Comment: @MarkAdams Whats wrong with bounds rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The `sender` in this case was the button who triggered the click event. You shouldn't use the button to present the popover in, but instead the real view where you want to present the popover.

2) Are you sure `addPopOverVC` was initialized and retained correctly?

cheers,
anka

Comment: Isn't button itself a UIView?
addPopOverVC is a viewController and use its been retained .

Comment: I tried it myself and it works for me, so I still think that your `addPopOverVC` isn't a valid object.

Comment: I have made a double check on that. It's neither nil nor deallocated. If it would have been nil then and message passed to nil have no effect . If it would have been deallocated then it would have crashed on first line (which is easy to detect with zombie flag) not at second line. I feel there is something wrong with my parameters !! any feedback on that

Comment: Ok. so finally I figured out . you were really close enough . addPopOverVC had a (sleep) in its viewdidload method. causing it to freeze. Thank you . I appreciate your help :)